# Nginx, Rails and Oauth. upstream prematurely closed connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, nginx

I have a strange problem that appears in production environment only when I use nginx and unicorn. When I use unicorn without nginx, it doesn't happen.

The problem. I have a simple oauth authentication which allows users to signup through GitHub. After pressing "allow" on GitHub's authorization page, the user is being redirected to callback route. And then, he/she gets `302 Bad Gateway` error.
Nginx log shows me this error  (keys are replaced by "...")

> 2012/12/26 18:03:08 [error] 1467#0: *1 upstream prematurely closed
>   connection while reading response header from upstream, client:
>   10.0.2.2, server: _, request: "GET /auth/github/callback?code=&state=...
>   HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.tm.sock:/auth/github/callback?code=...&state=...",
>   host: "localhost:3000"

Ther is my nginx config.

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.tm.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;

  client_max_body_size 4G;
  server_name _;

  keepalive_timeout 75s;

  proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
  proxy_read_timeout 60s;


  root /vagrant/public;

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;

  location @app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://unicorn;

    proxy_buffer_size 16k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 16k;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
}
```

So my question is why does this happen and is there any possible fix for it?

I have been googling it for a while, but without luck.

update

Thanks for the comment, I have just tried to set `fail_timeout=30s` and it does help, however request takes about 40s to complete. But thanks anyway, I'll try to expirement with this parameters.

I updated my config a bit, according to suggestions, but still, get the same error.

Also, this is unicorn error log. Seems like it kills request which takes longer than 30s but I guess redirection from oauth site cannot possibly be that long...

```
(github) Request phase initiated.
(github) Callback phase initiated.
E, [2012-12-26T19:33:13.058183 #6002] ERROR -- : worker=0 PID:6005 timeout (31s > 30s), killing
E, [2012-12-26T19:33:13.067011 #6002] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 6005 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=0
I, [2012-12-26T19:33:13.067198 #6002]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2012-12-26T19:33:13.068631 #6012]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=6012
I, [2012-12-26T19:33:13.068726 #6012]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2012-12-26T19:33:17.140948 #6012]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
```

unicorn config

```
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'production'

worker_processes 1

listen "/tmp/unicorn.tm.sock", :backlog => 64
listen 8080, :tcp_nopush => true

timeout 30

pid "/tmp/unicorn.pid"

stderr_path "/tmp/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "/tmp/unicorn.log"

check_client_connection false
```

Comment: have you tried adjust keepalive_timeout?

Comment: @EvgeniyRyzhkov, yes, I tried to increase it, but it didn't help. Same error appears in the log.

Comment: interesting fail_timeout actually nothing to do with with upstream response time http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule#server documentation suggest use proxy_connect_timeout and proxy_read_timeout for controlling upstream response time

Comment: have you tried remove or set up default value? http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#keepalive_timeout

Comment: Yup, I added proxy_connection_timeout and proxy_read_timeout with 60s, but same thing happening again

Comment: sorry for misleading you with fail_timeout parameter

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
ERROR -- : worker=0 PID:6005 timeout (31s > 30s), killing
```

You just need setup timeout to more then 30 in you unicorn config

Try at least

```
timeout 60
```

http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Unicorn/Configurator.html#method-i-timeout

Comment: Thank you for the help. Changing timeout to 60s in unicorn's config fixed the error. Serving this request takes exactly 31s though, but the question was about the error and not slow request so I think will figure out the rest of the problem.

Comment: did you manage to figure out why it's taking so long? I'm also seeing something similar with our rails/unicorn/nginx mix occasionally...

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue with Shopify. @evfwcqcg -- will be great if you can update the answer about what was causing the slow request.

Comment: The slow request can come from a slow API calls, lots of API calls or by lots of processing by a unicorn. Remember that increasing a unicorn timeout means a user has to sit there for 30+ seconds. Chances are you'll need to move that processing (or multiple calls) to a background job.